# Find the number of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V$ is vector space with dimension $p^2$ defined on a finite field $F$. How many subspaces of **dimension one**, $V$ has?

Comment: You mean $V$ is a vector space, I think, and I suppose $F$ is a finite field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: each subspace of dimension $1$ is spanned by a nonzero vector.  How many of those are there?  How many vectors span the same subspace?

Comment: I know that we have at most $q^2-1$ elements. But I was told that there are $q-1$ elements reiteratively. I don't know how this later occurs.

Comment: How many elements does the field $F$ have?

Comment: I am so sorry. The Field has $p$ elements and I confused $p$ with $q$ in my previuos comment.

Comment: So there are $p^{p^2}$ vectors in $V$, of which all but $1$ are nonzero.  Now, how many span the same $1$-dimensional subspace?